# query result cachnig in OrientDB and Neo4j

Tags: caching, neo4j, orientdb

just out of curiosity, does anybody know if Neo4j and OrientDB implement caching of query results, that is, storing in cache a query together with its result, so that subsequent requests of the same query are served without actually computing  the result of the query.

Notice that this is different from caching part of the DB since in this case the query would be anyway executed (possibly using only data taken from memory instead of disk).

Answer (score 2):

Starting from release v2.2 (not in SNAPSHOT but will be RC in few days), OrientDB supports caching of commands results. Caching command results has been used by other DBMSs and proven to dramatically improve the following use cases:

- database is mostly read than write
- there are a few heavy queries that result a small result set
- you have available RAM to use or caching results

By default, the command cache is disabled. To enable it, set command.timeout=true.

For more information: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Command-Cache.html.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of layers where you can put the caching. You can put it at the highest level behind Varnish ( https://www.varnish-cache.org )  or some other high level cache. You can use a KV store like Redis ( http://redis.io ) and store a result with an expiration. You can also cache within Neo4j using extensions. Both simple things like index look-ups, partial traversals or complete results. See http://maxdemarzi.com/2014/03/23/caching-partial-traversals/ or http://maxdemarzi.com/2015/02/27/caching-immutable-id-lookups-in-neo4j/ for some ideas.